# React close tab backend request not refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Exit when the page is refreshed :( help

**Code:**

```
useEffect(() => {
  const handleBeforeUnload = async (event) => {
    try {
      const cookies = new Cookies();
      cookies.remove("_token");
      const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:3001/logout", {
        withCredentials: true,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Hata:", error);
    }
  };
  window.addEventListener("beforeunload", handleBeforeUnload);
  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", handleBeforeUnload);
  };
}, []);
```

Only exit when the tab is closed

Comment: Please add more description of what you want and what is happening now. The description is very little. It's hard to understand the problem

Comment: @moshfiqrony I want to send a request to the backend when the tab is closed but it also does this when the page is refreshed.

This is definitely it.

Comment: If you don't set an expiry date on your cookies it defaults to expire at the end of the session, no need to delete them manually.

Comment: @reyno My problem is not with cookies, I want to know this in the backend when a user logs out.

Comment: Add more description what you want to achieve, Question is not clear.

Comment: @MaulikPatel I want to send a request to the backend when the tab is closed but it also does this when the page is refreshed. This is definitely it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`beforeunload` will call in both cases ( In tab close event and a page refresh event). but, you can use `visibilitychange` event here. You can add condition like this.

**Logic for check page is refreshed or not**

```
if (document.visibilityState !== "hidden") {
  console.log("Page is being refreshed");
  return;
}
```

**Full code:**

```
useEffect(() => {
  const handleBeforeUnload = async (event) => {
    try {
      const cookies = new Cookies();
      cookies.remove("_token");
      // Check if the page is being refreshed or closed
      if (document.visibilityState !== "hidden") {
        console.log("Page is being refreshed");
        return;
      }
      // If not a refresh, proceed with the logout logic
      const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:3001/logout", {
        withCredentials: true,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error:", error);
    }
  };

  window.addEventListener("beforeunload", handleBeforeUnload);

  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", handleBeforeUnload);
  };
}, []);
```

I have done this way in past, I don't know this is the best way or not. Let me know, if you have any doubts.

Comment: You're welcome bro. It's more of a workaround, but I believe there isn't a specific event in JavaScript available for these types of situations.

Comment: If I close the tab on the project page the method don't work :(

Comment: It should work cause document.visibilityState = "hidden" in that case and it should call the API.

Answer (score -1):

Try VisibilityChange event listener
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/visibilitychange_event

Comment: This could be used as part of a workaround, but on its own this doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).